# Prevent selecting same value in three different dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have three dropdowns. I want that when the user selects any item from dropdown 1, then that item should be disabled in dropdown 2 and 3. Also, if an item is selected in dropdown 2, then both selected items must be disabled from dropdown 3.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function updateSelect(changedSelect, selectId) {
      var otherSelect = document.getElementById(selectId);
      for (var i = 0; i < otherSelect.options.length; ++i) {
        otherSelect.options[i].disabled = false;
      }
      if (changedSelect.selectedIndex == 0) {
        return;
      }
      otherSelect.options[changedSelect.selectedIndex].disabled = true;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="select_1"  onchange="updateSelect(this,'select_2'),updateSelect(this,'select_3');"   name="indication_subject[]">
    <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
    <option value="1"> Accounting</option>
    <option value="2"> Afrikaans</option>
    <option value="3"> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
    <option value="4"> Arabic</option>
    <option value="5"> Art and Design</option>
    <option value="6"> Biology</option>
    <option value="7"> Business Studies</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select_2" name="indication_subject[]" onchange="updateSelect(this,'select_1','select_3');" >
    <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
    <option value="1"> Accounting</option>
    <option value="2"> Afrikaans</option>
    <option value="3"> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
    <option value="4"> Arabic</option>
    <option value="5"> Art and Design</option>
    <option value="6"> Biology</option>
    <option value="7"> Business Studies</option>
  </select>
  <select id="select_3" name="indication_subject[]" onchange="updateSelect(this,'select_1','select_2');" >
    <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
   <option value="1"> Accounting</option>
   <option value="2"> Afrikaans</option>
   <option value="3"> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
   <option value="4"> Arabic</option>
   <option value="5"> Art and Design</option>
   <option value="6"> Biology</option>
   <option value="7"> Business Studies</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the JSFiddle link which works for two dropdowns, not three. How can I add a third dropdown for this?

http://jsfiddle.net/x4E5Q/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try This:

**HTML**

```
<select id="select1" name="indication_subject[]">
  <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
  <option value="1"> Accounting</option>
  <option value="2"> Afrikaans</option>
  <option value="3"> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
  <option value="4"> Arabic</option>
  <option value="5"> Art and Design</option>
  <option value="6"> Biology</option>
  <option value="7"> Business Studies</option>
</select>

<select id="select2" name="indication_subject[]">
  <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
  <option value="1"> Accounting</option>
  <option value="2"> Afrikaans</option>
  <option value="3"> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
  <option value="4"> Arabic</option>
  <option value="5"> Art and Design</option>
  <option value="6"> Biology</option>
  <option value="7"> Business Studies</option>
</select>

<select id="select3" name="indication_subject[]">
  <option value="" selected="selected">a </option>
  <option value="1"> Accounting</option>
  <option value="2"> Afrikaans</option>
  <option value="3"> Applied Information and Communication Technology</option>
  <option value="4"> Arabic</option>
  <option value="5"> Art and Design</option>
  <option value="6"> Biology</option>
  <option value="7"> Business Studies</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("select").change(function() {   
    $("select").not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() + "]").attr('disabled', true);
  }); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x4E5Q/137/)

Comment: it works but it does not hide the item of second bar select accounting in first then africa in second and applied in three then see the results

Comment: instead of showing alert it should be also disable as other are

Comment: instead of error it may disable it also in the dropdown so that user may not select prevoiusly selected

Comment: please test place Accounting in first Afrika in second then again it should not show both option in third(i.e Accounting and Afrikans)

Comment: it doesnot show it disabled but the user will not be able to select it! is not thatr enough? :)

Comment: it will not look good according to flow it should be disabled as other are

Comment: if i am adding this code in my file it does not work i have also included jquerry

Comment: add : `<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> before calling your own script!

Comment: Hi, using `disabled` prevents the value from `Posting` to Server, *how can we achieve the same - but also get it to POST*

Comment: @Transformer you need to remove the disabled attribute before send it to Server

Answer (score 0):

```
See below code

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("select").on('hover', function () {
            $previousValue = $(this).val();
        }).change(function() {
            $("select").not(this).find("option[value='"+ $(this).val() + "']").attr('disabled', true);
            $("select").not(this).find("option[value='"+ $previousValue + "']").attr('disabled', false);
        });
    });

$("#confirm-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("select").find("option").removeAttr('disabled');
    document.getElementById('confirm-form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Hi, using `disabled` prevents the value from `Posting` to Server, *how can we achieve the same - but also get it to POST*

Comment: @transformer : Yes that's correct but we can remove the disabled attribute on form submit. Please see the updated code.

Comment: Thanks, that was wonderful. If you want to answer this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45683578/6085193) ... I can mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

  $("select").on('focus', function () {
        $("select").find("option[value='"+ $(this).val() + "']").attr('disabled', false);
    }).change(function() {

        $("select").not(this).find("option[value='"+ $(this).val() + "']").attr('disabled', true);

    });


});
```