# Not allowing select same value from db , but select inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to select a value from db inside javascript. Why is this not working if the select is inside javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = <?php foreach ($results2 as $rss) { ?><?php echo $rss["qty"]; ?><?php } ?>; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 0; //initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div><br><tr><td><label for="kind">Part Number / part Name</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="qty">Quatity (Pcs)</label><br><select name="kind[]" class="select1" required><option value="">Please Select</option><?php foreach ($results1 as $rs) { ?><option value="<?php echo $rs["part_number"]; ?>/<?php echo $rs["part_name"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["part_number"]; ?>  --  <?php echo $rs["part_name"]; ?></option><?php } ?></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="qty[]" value="" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" required/></td></tr><tr></tr><a href="#" class="remove_field">&nbsp;Hapus</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
}) });
```

this for hidden if before select in dropdown

```
  $(document).ready(function(){   
$("select").change(function() {   
$('select[name="kind[]"]').not(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val() + "]").attr('hidden', true); }); });
```

I learned from here
[Prevent selecting same value in three different dropdowns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041789/not-allow-select-same-value-with-three-dropdown-in-html-javascript)

Comment: can you post your full code here with html and everything as possible

Comment: What does `max_fields` end up as? Seems like that'd be an invalid variable value(s). Are you getting error messages?

Comment: @chris85 not getting error

Comment: as you are setting `max_fields`  to probably be an array (more values) you can not do this conditional `if(x < max_fields){`. If `max_fields` is an integer then you need to review the way you are getting this value.

Comment: problem not max_fields , but if dropdown before I select , example value 1 , in next dropdown value 1 stiil appear

Comment: somebody can help me